# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning without any details

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

After updating to Xcode 8.3.2 I got an Apple Mach-O Linker Warning when trying to run on a device (It's working on simulator). But I did not get any details. Double click on the error does not bring more informations about the linker warning. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Restart XCode, Clean(Command+Shift+K) and Build(Command+Shift+B) your project. And if you are using pods make sure you are opening .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click (or control-click) the error message and choose “Reveal in Log”.

[image: revealing the log]

For this demo, I forced a linker error by manually truncating one of my .o files. Your error will probably be something else.

The first thing to try if you can't tell make sense of the linker error (once you find it in the log) is to do a clean build. Hold the option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) and choose Product > Clean Build Folder…. Then choose Product > Build.

Comment: Perfect! That's it :-) Thx